# Can AfferoGPLv3 code be used in GPLv3 code?

Tags: licensing, gpl, agpl

Can software with AGPLv3 license be used with GPLv3 project?

Can the resulting project be GPLv3, or must it have the special requirements of AGPLv3?

I am not very smart from clause 13 of GLPv3 that mentions AGPLv3.

> Notwithstanding any other provision of this License, you have
>   permission to link or combine any covered work with a work licensed
>   under version 3 of the GNU Affero General Public License into a single
>   combined work, and to convey the resulting work. The terms of this
>   License will continue to apply to the part which is the covered work,
>   but the special requirements of the GNU Affero General Public License,
>   section 13, concerning interaction through a network will apply to the
>   combination as such.

Must the resulting, combined work be AGPLv3 or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resulting combined work would need to be AGPL. Here is a handy chart that explains many popular licensees. Arrows indicate that two licenses may be combined, and that the combined work can effectively be treated as having the license at the end of the arrow, possibly with some additional restrictions taken from the license at the start of the arrow.

[image]